# Share variables in real time. Multiprocess Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

I have 2 process: The process `A` generates the data and the process `B` performs math calculations whit the values of the process `A`. The process are synchronized via the Multiprocess library from Python as can show it in the code below. Until now, the way that I am sharing variables is via the data types `value` or `Array` that provides the `Multiprocess` library. If I understand how it work these data types, is neccessary wait to the process has finished to use the shared variable, so, in this way I understand that I can not use immediately a new value generated (or array) by the process A.

The process A that generates the data is:

```
def process_A(processid, textid, texttitle, values):
    
    iters = 10
    
    h1 = new_data_incoming()
    data  = h1.text.split(" ")

    p_var1, p_var2 = 0, 0
    i = 0
    while i < iters:
        
        a_var1 = float(data[1].replace(',',''))
        a_var2 = float(data[1].replace(',',''))
        if a_var1 != p_var1:
            values[0] = a_var1
            values[1] = a_var2
            values[2] = float(data[3].replace(',',''))
            values[3] = float(data[4].replace(',',''))
            
            if data[5][0] == "+":
                values[4] = float(data[5][1::])
            else:
                values[4] = -float(data[5][1::])
                
            if data[6][0] == "+":
                values[5] = float(data[6][1:-1])
            else:
                values[5] = -float(data[6][1:-1])
            
            p_var1 = a_var1
            p_var2 = a_var2
            i = i + 1
```

The process B that controls the launch of the process A and receive the data is:

```
def process_B():
    ids = getids()
    
    key2 = "stocastic_process"
    
    id2  = ids[key2]
    
    values = Array('d', range(6))
    
    process_A_launched = Process(target=process_A, args=(2, id2, key2, values2))
    
    process_A_launched.start()
    print("Process with id %i has started: stocastic %s" % (2, key2))
    
    process_A_launched.join(timeout=0)
    
    finished = False
    fnsh = False
    
    while finished == False:
            
        if not process_A_launched.is_alive() and fnsh == False:
            print("process %i has finished!" % (2))
            fnsh = True
            
        if fnsh == True:
            finished = True
    
    print("All process have finished!")

    do_somethig_with_values(values)
```

So, I want to use as soon as possible the new data generated. Always that the process A has generated a new data, uses it in the process B, because my intention is that the process A is running all the time. Maybe I need to use pipes?

In C, I have used pipes and interruptions with POSIX, but I don't know about this in Python.

Thanks!

Comment: How about using a blocking Queue for A to put the data and multiple consumers B on the Queue to use the values. If you want to use latest value always then instead of Queue you can use Stack in similar way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle being thread-safe yourself with a blocking mutex (`Lock()`) or use a queue, depending on how much data you have to send.

### Using a mutex

```py
from multiprocessing import Lock
from time import sleep
from collections import dequeue
data = dequeue()
lock = Lock()

def producer():
    with lock:
        data.append(stuff)
    ...
    with lock:
        data.append(stuff)

def launcher_consumer():
    start_producer()
    while not len(data):
        sleep(0.001)
    with lock:
        do_stuff(data.pop_left())
```

However by this point... we've pretty much reimplemented a queue.  I'd only use a mutex if I had one (or maybe two) bits of data to send.  (In the first case I wouldn't use a dequeue, just an ordinary var.)

### Using a queue

```
from multiprocessing import Queue

data = Queue()

def producer():
    data.put(stuff)
    ...
    data.put(stuff)

def launcher_consumer():
    start_producer()
    val = data.get(timeout=None) # set timeout if you need it
    do_stuff(val)
    val = data.get()
    do_stuff(val)
```

For more information on either solution, see the multiprocessing docs.

### References

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes